# How to display as textbox by using select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Is there anyway using [Select2](http://select2.github.io/select2/) displaying as textbox instead of a select tool look?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs:

> Select2 also supports multi-value select boxes. The select below is
>   declared with the multiple attribute. Select2 automatically picks up
>   on this:

```
<select multiple>...</select>
```

This is what gives the 'text box' look.

Or, if you are only after a single selection you could just change the CSS styles of the existing select tool to make it 'look' like a standard text box.

Answer (score 0):

Steven, this is true, however, display is using tags and I guess we all want the input/box view.

Based on select2 v4.0.0, it seems we can choose his adapter (single or multiple), but I have been unable to force it (nor enter free entry !)